# Patent searching in biotechnology

Tags: patent-search, biotechnology, enzyme, dna

Is anyone experienced in searching patent applications/patents whose subject is either an enzyme (protein sequence) and/or the gene which encodes a particular enzyme (dna sequence)? There should be a way to search across the sequences.

Comment: I don't have any experience but have seen this, maybe it helps: https://www.lens.org/lens/bio

Comment: @DonQuiKong thanks a lot! It certainly answers my question, why don't you place it as an actual answer?

Comment: Because I hadn't tried it out and didn't know if it was even remotely what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lens has a search machine for sequences plus some analytics tools at [lens.org/lens/bio](http://lens.org/lens/bio)

Comment: With special thanks to EricShain for always promoting the lens

Comment: EricShain is indeed an accurate source of information. But so is DonQuiKong :)

Comment: @chempatent1981 thx :D